# Pronunciation of words ending in -n

Tags: pronunciación, diferencias-regionales

It seems that some people pronounce words that end with -n almost as a "ng" sound.  "Bien", for example, seems to come out as "Bie[ng]".

Is this a regional issue?  What regions use this pronunciation?  Is this true only for words *ending* in -n or does the letter n ever get pronounced that way when it's inside of the word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a regional dialect.  However, it's a dialect is only prominent for words ending in -n.

#### The Dialect

In the majority of dialects, a word ending in -n is alveolar (your basic "n" sound in English, such as "begin").

However, is some dialects, the final -n sound is articulated further back in the mouth.  At it's most extreme, it can become a velar nasal sound, sound similar "long" or "bang".

However, this distinction isn't quite as pronounced as the question implies--there's no articulated "g" sound on the end of the words.  But it does seem to carry that velar nasal sound we see in "long" or "song".

#### Regions

This velar "-n" is common in some parts of Spain, the Caribbean, some Central American dialects, as well as coastal areas of some countries in South America.

See also: [Wikipedia: velar -n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dialects_and_varieties#Word-final_.22-n.22)